# Split up query results after loading XML with fn:string-join in an Oracle table

Tags: oracle, xmltype

I've loaded a few XML files into an Oracle database (11gr2 on Linux x64) and I had to use a fn:string-join to succesfully import the xml files which contain multiple records.

After the data has landed/has been imported to an XMLTYPE table using SQL*LOADER, i've issued a query which transports the XML data from the XMLTYPE table to a regular table, lets call that one Table_A

This table now contains all fields of the imported records (2 records in this case) together in the target fields, so for instance.

The xml file contains an entry for computer_brand and the first record has the value 'Dell' and the second record has got the value 'Apple'.
Now the two records from the XML file have been select/inserted in to Table_A but are in the same field, separated by a semi-colon.
Field name: computer_brand
Values: Dell;Apple

What I'd like to do is select the separate values from the table (regardless from the number of different values in the field, since this query needs to run from a scheduled job) and pass them through to insert all the values in their own separate fields.

---

Here's an example of the things i've made/used:

---

Table_A metadata:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a
(
computer_brand                           varchar2(41),
owner                                    varchar2(101),
address                                  varchar2(101),
serialnumber                             varchar2(21)
)
```

I've selected and inserted the data imported from the xmltype table into Table_A with the following query:

```
insert into table_a
(computer_brand,
 owner,
 address,
 serialnumber
)
select
 a.computer_brand,
 a.owner,
 a.address,
 a.serialnumber
from table_xml a,
 xmltable (xmlnamespaces('not mentioned due to security reasons' as "tns"),
 '//tns:Main' passing a.xml_file
 columns
 computer_brand      varchar2(41)  path 'fn:string-join(tns:/@computer_brand,";")',
 owner               varchar2(101) path 'fn:string-join(tns:/@owner,";")',
 address             varchar2(101) path 'fn:string-join(tns:/@address,";")',
 serialnumber        varchar2(21)  path 'fn:string-join(tns:/serialnumber,";")')
(+) k
where upper(file_name)=upper('xmlfile.xml');
```

The output for the above query is:

```
computer_brand
--------------
dell;apple

owner
--------------
pete;jack

address
--------------
basement;attic

serialnumber
--------------
123444;456555
```

Enormous thanks in advance if someone would know how to and help out? I was looking at `SUBSTR()` didn't really manage to fix it..

Comment: Anyone maybe have an idea or possible solution? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well that's what string-join is supposed to do: It Concatenates values matching the XPath. So in fact what you are looking for is just your query without the string-join. I don't know exactly how your XML looks like but I would suggest to try an SQL like this:

```
insert into table_a
(computer_brand,
 owner,
 address,
 serialnumber
)
select
 a.computer_brand,
 a.owner,
 a.address,
 a.serialnumber
from table_xml a,
 xmltable (xmlnamespaces('not mentioned due to security reasons' as "tns"),
 '//tns:Main' passing a.xml_file
 columns
 computer_brand      varchar2(41)  path 'tns:/@computer_brand',
 owner               varchar2(101) path 'tns:/@owner)',
 address             varchar2(101) path 'tns:/@address)',
 serialnumber        varchar2(21)  path 'tns:/serialnumber')
(+) k
where upper(file_name)=upper('xmlfile.xml');
```